# Lambda Expression : Pick out a substring from a larger string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, linq

This is the string which iam trying to process

```
var str = 
  "$filter=HRRepName ne null and HRRepName ne '' and HRRepName eq 'jessica.l.hessling'&$top=1"
```

Currently using below code to get the substring `- jessica.l.hessling`

```
var repName = odataQuery
  .Split(new string[] { "eq" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
  .Split(new char[] { (char)39 })[1]
  .Replace("'", "")
  .Trim();
```

But this index might create bug later hence i want to use lambda expression.

What I have tried till now :

```
var repName2 = odataQuery
 .Split(new string[] { "HRRepName" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
 .Select(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("eq",StringComparison.Ordinal)+1));
```

Comment: the question is quite good so far, but could you generalize a little more about the pattern that defines the substring that you are looking for ? What in that input string is fixed and what can change?

Comment: Your code will anyway fail on strings that contain `eq` in them (e.g. `equator`). It is not clear how you are going to fix that with a lambda.

Comment: Mong Zhu : i have mentioned the string which i am looking for jessica.l.hessling , this can be any name , i want the string right after eq but before '&'

Comment: It seems you actually want to *parse* (or at least *tokenize*) the string (you are working with some kind of query language like sql). What if you have and `"...HRRepName eq 'master.mequ'&$top=1"` string? Please, note that `eq` is a *part of the name* now and thus both `Split` and `Substring` solutions will be incorrect.

Comment: can 2 names appear in the string? so `eq` and `&` also be twice in there ?

Comment: This would be a lot better with a few more input samples, and a definition of how much variation there can be.

Comment: Right now I would pick a RegEx for this. Did you consider that?

Comment: This looks like an OData filter to me. You could look how [Microsoft handles this themselves](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/tree/887a7e3920191798e44338ffc79ea85873347457/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/Query), but personally I would use ANTLR for parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think Regex might be very good choice here, try below code:

```
var str = "$filter=HRRepName ne null and HRRepName ne '' and HRRepName eq 'jessica.l.hessling'&$top=1";
var match = (new Regex(@"HRRepName eq '([^']+)")).Match(str);
var extractedString = match.Success ? match.Groups[1] : null;
```

Explanation: `HRRepName eq '([^']+)` will match `HRRepName eq '` literally, then it will match everything until `'` character with `([^']+)`, brackets mean, that it will be stored in capture group.

Comment: Judging this is an OData filter, you can't rely on the exact order of `$top`, `$filter` and others.

Comment: As far as i know, c# can use the `positive lookbehind`, is there a reason to avoid it or would something like `(?<=HRRepName eq ')([^']+)` fit better?

Comment: @LittleBit Well, you are right, it could fit the requirements, but it is unnecessary. I don't know if OP knows regex well and lookarounds aren't basic tools. Also, it could reduce performance of regex :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> this can be any name , i want the string right after eq but before '&'

To find whether items are in a string, and/or extract substrings from a string according to some pattern, RegEx is usually the way to go.

To fetch the data after the first eq and before the first & after this eq:

```
const string regexPattern = ".*eq(.*)&";
var match = RegEx.Match(regexPattern);
if (match.Success)
{    // found the pattern, it is in Match.Groups
     ProcessMatch(match.Groups[1]); // [0] is complete matching string, [1] is first capture
}
```

The pattern:

- `*.` start the string with zero or more characters
- `eq` until the first occurrence of eq
- `(*.)` capture zero or more characters
- `&` until the first & after this eq

You can test this using one of the [online RegEx pattern testers](https://regex101.com/)

The captured item is in Match.Groups. I haven't tested it, but as far as I remember, this is an IList, where element [0] is the complete matching string, [1](https://regex101.com/) is the first captured item. Your debugger will show this to you.